# Django translation not working on production

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, django-i18n

I've made translation of the site for different cities and it works fine on dev machine. But when published on production server it didn't show any translation.

But it shows available languages and current language correctly.

Here's my settings.py:

```
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LANGUAGES = [
    ('ru-spb', _('SaintP')),
    ('ru-msk', _('Moscow')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'nordicsite/locale'),
)
```

Here's template for language check:

```
 {% load i18n %}
 {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
 {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %} 
 {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}

 {{server}}<br/>
 {% trans 'Test 2' %}<br/>
 {{LANGUAGE_CODE}}<br/>
 {% for language in languages %}
     {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})<br/>
 {% endfor %}
 <br/>
 {% for path in paths %}
     {{path}}<br/>
 {% endfor %}
```

Output for dev:

```
Тест 1 Питер
Тест 2 Питер
ru-spb
Русский (ru) 
Русский (ru) 

/*****/nordicsite/locale
```

Output for production:

```
Test 1
Test 2
ru-spb
Русский (ru) 
Русский (ru) 

/*****/nordicsite/locale
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Have you compiled the .po files into .mo and deployed them in production ?

Comment: Oh and yes: have you restarted your server process too ?

Comment: @bruno-desthuilliers yes, files deployed and locale_paths are correct. Asked hosting provider to restart processes for my user.

Comment: Note that you do have to restart the server process(es) each time you update your code so you may want to check with your hosting how you can do it by yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i figured out what was wrong. My dev machine - Mac and production - Ubuntu. And it didn't work width fake language codes like ru-spb and ru-msk. I changed it to ru-ru and ru-ua and started working correctly.

One more thing. Ubuntu needs locale folder to be ru_RU (not ru_ru).

Comment: I made all the suggestions you show but nothing that works the translations of my site...

Comment: I changed the case in the locale folder and the LANGUAGE_CODE to my "second" language and it worked. It always falls back to English or uses my second language, in the example should be ru_RU